# Why does Internet Explorer Cache xhr requests?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, http, xmlhttprequest

I see a lot of questions on how to fix overly-aggressive caching with IE and Ajax but I can't seem to find any information on why they would do such a thing. Is there ever a reason to cache ajax calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching the ajax results is wise for the same reasons you cache non-ajax responses. You don't want to make a round-trip back to the server if you already have the data in cache. If you want to force the trip to be made, you could instruct the data to *not* be cached via the response headers, or use of the various other methods for cache-busting like appending the current timestamp to the request's query-string.

Comment: Those are two completely different things. Caching HTML, CSS, JavaScript, images and whatever is wise, caching DATA is almost never "wise". IE is the only browser that does this.

Comment: XHR isn't meant exclusively for raw data. People use it to load pages, prompts, dialogs, and more. It's not just a way to pass JSON or (gasp) XML around. And even data is wise to cache at times as well.

Comment: Yeah, you can do these things, and it would be fine to cache it when used for other than data. But that's when you should put on the cache header, not the other way around. IE is alone in thinking this is a good idea.